# tableview gets blank screen for first time , and gives correct details on later visits?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am displaying tableview , and all the calls to database is being done viewDidLoad , where i am creating an array .This array is then passed to tableview for populatiing rows .The latest code is at 
http://www.codeshare.io/MRKQD

Comment: can you post some code where the arr data load

Comment: have you checked same code in viewWillAppear.

Comment: I am  trying to display two labels in one cell . Any alternative solutions could be useful .

Answer (score -3):

After updating your array, reload the TableView data again. 
Just call:

```
[yourTableViewName reloadData];
```

Comment: i have tried that , and still it's still showing blank screen initially

Comment: I did add that in questions details .